# How to add Jenkins slave (Java web start) using CURL?

Tags: automation, jenkins, slave

I was able to create a bash script to use Curl (doCreateItem) to create SSH slave which would show up in Jenkins ---> Nodes  without a problem, My question is how to create slave with Java Web start launch method, Or at least a way to change the launch method from SSH to JNLP using the API. I have requirements that Master can't initiate the connection therefore JNLP must be used. current script runs on RHEL7.

="${JENKINS_URL}/computer/doCreateItem?name=${NODE_NAME}&type=hudson.slaves.DumbSlave")

[Jenkins Launcher method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kwEx.png)
Thanks